# Does Selenium do UI testing?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was wondering if we can use selenium for UI testing.  Does it support Javascripts on modern browsers?  What other open source tools do you recommend?
I have googled a bit but could not get any definitive answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Selenium` is a tool you can use to mimic a user interacting with a web browser. If your UI Testing is browser based, then yes you can use it.

While selenium allows you to execute javascript commands directly, you shouldn't need to do that very often as it just does things you'd expect a user to do: clicking a button, filling out a form, etc...

It's become such a widely used tool, that it's hard to find strong reasons to use anything else, although other options exist. There are other tools that are built on top of `Selenium` that can help with testing other things.

Testing Web Browsers:
Selenium

Testing apps: Appium

Testing angular: Protractor

Testing Windows apps: Winium

Selenium's `WebDriver` has started to be implemented by the major browsers directly as Selenium has been influential is pushing that into the w3 standard. This makes it so it's the responsibility of the browsers to update their `WebDriver` when they release new versions, which has been and will be helpful to maintain stability in selenium tests as browsers update.

In short, yes selenium is for browser based UI Testing.